# What does the growingElements function in QuickCheck do?

Tags: haskell

I was poking around the documentation of QuickCheck when I stumbled into the [growingElements](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:growingElements) function. The documentation there says

> Takes a list of elements of increasing size, and chooses among an
>   initial segment of the list. The size of this initial segment
>   increases with the size parameter. The input list must be non-empty.

What exactly does this mean? When I tried this function in ghci, 
it just returns random values in the a given array when I run `generate` on it again and again. I don't see the difference between randomly choosing from the list and what this function is doing.

```
*Main Test.QuickCheck> generate $ growingElements [1..100]
13
*Main Test.QuickCheck> generate $ growingElements [1..100]
53
*Main Test.QuickCheck> 
*Main Test.QuickCheck> generate $ growingElements [1..100]
65
*Main Test.QuickCheck> generate $ growingElements [1..100]
49
*Main Test.QuickCheck>
```

Could someone explain more clearly what this function actually does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickCheck has a "size parameter" that controls how big the randomly generated inputs can be. It starts by generating smaller test inputs and increases them as it runs more and more tests.

The QuickCheck manual goes into [more detail](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#15) about this:

> Test data generators have an implicit *size* parameter; `quickCheck` begins by generating small test cases, and gradually increases the size as testing progresses. Different test data generators interpret the size parameter in different ways: some ignore it, while the list generator, for example, interprets it as an upper bound on the length of generated lists. You are free to use it as you wish to control your own test data generators.

In the case of `growingElements`, the size parameter controls how far into the list the generator looks when selecting an entry at random.

If you want to play around with the `size` parameter yourself, you can use the `sized` combinator:

```
sized :: (Int -> Gen a) -> Gen a
```

This lets you write your own `Gen a` values that depend on the size passed in. Here's what `growingElements` could look like:

```
growingElements' xs = sized (\ size -> oneOf (take size xs))
```

If you want to see how the existing `growingElements` behaves at different sizes, you can fix a particular size using the `resize` function. Try

```
resize 1 (growingElements [1..])
```

which should only return smallish numbers from the beginning of the list. (I looked up [the actual implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#growingElements) and it uses some fiddly arithmetic to choose the number of elements based on the size parameter, so I'm too lazy to figure out exactly how it behaveds :)).

Comment: QuickCheck's vague notion of "size" is the aspect of the library I find most unsatisfactory. Lots of things in QuickCheck just "do the obviously right thing", but as soon as size enters the picture it goes fuzzy and leaves the user with little guidance about how to make the fiddly judgement calls.